# Finding it difficult to achieve photo grid layout

Tags: html, image, css, grid, flexbox

i'm finding it difficult to achieve this exact photo grid any ideas on how to go about it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsP1t.png)

for clarification, i already had working prototype [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fARb6.png) which was done with flexbox but one wasnt fiting in well so i had to use position absolute which doesnt work well when displayed on other screen size.

Heres was my code

```css
.container-ed {
  padding: 0px 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.pic-ed {
  position: relative;
}

.pic-ar {
  position: absolute;
  right: 40px;
  margin-top: 280px;
}

.pic-ad {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-ed">
      <img class="pic-ed" src="img/pic.svg" height="550" width="600">
     <!-- <img class="x-ed" src="img/ex-ed.svg"> -->
      <img class="pic-ad" src="img/Rectangle%20136.svg" height="250" width="300">
      <img class="pic-ad" src="img/Rectangle%20136.svg" height="250" width="300">
      <img class="pic-ad" src="img/Rectangle%20136.svg" height="250" width="300">
      <img class="pic-ad" src="img/Rectangle%20136.svg" height="250" width="300">
      <img class="pic-ar" src="img/Rectangle%20136.svg" height="250" width="300">

    </div>
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Show an effort of your own and come back if you can't make it work. Here is a good read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @LGSon You see my previous effort now

Answer (score 1):

is this you are looking for?

```css
.photo-grid {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
.grid {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    background-color: #eee;
}
.grid:before {
    content: attr(data-label);
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    left: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #000;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.grid.small {
    width: 33.3%;
    height: 33.3%;
}
.grid.medium {
    width: 66.6%;
    height: 66.6%;
}
.grid.right {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo-grid">
    <div class="grid medium" data-label="1"></div>
    <div class="grid small" data-label="2"></div>
    <div class="grid small" data-label="3"></div>
    <div class="grid small right" data-label="4"></div>
    <div class="grid small right" data-label="5"></div>
    <div class="grid small right" data-label="6"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how responsive you want this to be. I would make a div element for the first 3 pictures and another for the bottom 3. set the size of the first image to be a higher proportion than the others and float them left.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using twitter bootstrap and appending different heights to the boxes. W3Schools has a tutorial on how to use it: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/

Comment: using a library / plugin for a smaller and single purpose is an overhead.

Comment: I understand. But it could also be helpful in the layout of other pages. I use bootstrap for responsive web design along with @media queries

Comment: It would be easier to do it one of the other ways. Just thought i would put another option

Comment: I don't think such a grid layout is possible in bootstrap., also bootstrap's grid system will make the grid elements to behave like blocks on lower screen resolutions. Which will be entirely different from the question.

Comment: I think you can if you position them absolutely but it will be unnecessary work

Comment: I actually did use absolute to complete the arrangement but i just felt there should be a better way because using absolute makes the arrangement scatter on a larger screen @ProgrammingLife